# How to change the minimum brightness value?

Tags: screen, brightness, system, system-settings, backlight

I want to dim brightness in my system way below the currently available setting. I found [this method](https://superuser.com/a/560458) which helps to set a minimum brightness value. But the problem is if I ever change the brightness then the minimum brightness moves back to the default value. To dim the brightness again, I have to rerun `sudo su -c "echo 2070 >/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness"` . How do we permanently change the default brightness value?

Answer (score 1):

The best way i with sysfsutils.

```
sudo apt install sysfsutils
```

create in under folder /etc/sysfs.d/ a file named brightness.conf with following content. The name  has to and with suffix .conf

```
class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness = 2070
```

Restart service

```
sudo systemctl restart sysfsconf.service
```

sorry for  [link](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysfs-rules.html) but I can not explain in english.